# Validate a field in Laravel only if it's zero or a value from db

Tags: validation, laravel

I'm new to Laravel so sorry for my newbie question:

I have in input field, it must be valid only if it's zero or if it's value exists in a "products" db table.
I'm using Form Request Validation with Laravel 5.2.

This is my code:

```
class CreateRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
      return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'product_id'    =>  'sometimes|exists:products,id'
        ];
    }
}
```

This works for the database validation, but how can I make it valid if it's zero?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suggest to write a custom validation for this, it's simple: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      'product_id' => 'integer|size:0|exists:products,id'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Custom validation rules

If you are using 5.6 you can create a custom rule or pass a closure

```
   class CreateRequest extends Request
    {
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
          return true;
        }


    public function rules()
        {
            return [
              'product_id'    =>  ['integer',  function($attribute, $value, $fail) {

            $product = Product::find($value);
                if ($value != 0 && !$product  ) {
                    return $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
                }
            },
            ];
        }
     }
```

Hope this helps